# How many edges are cut in a balanced partition of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, partition-problem

Consider a graph on *n* nodes and *e* edges that is partitioned into *k* "balanced" subgraphs in the sense that each block has an equal number of nodes and the number of cut edges is minimized. Is there a formula for the number of cut edges in this situation?

Comment: Your question is not well defined. Graph partitioning algorithms are based on what you are trying to optimize. For example that could be the cut edges themselves.

Comment: You are right on that. I have clarified the question

Answer (score 2):

Even in the current updated version of the question, it still remains ill defined. There many different ways by which you can partition a graph into symmetric (or balanced if you like) clusters. One question that you might have in mind but have problem expressing is the **minimum multisection** (or partition): *Given a graph $G$ find a symmetric partition $P$ of its vertices such that it minimizes the edges between different clusters.*

In which case the answer is that the problem is NP-hard [1] and moreover it is NP-hard to approximate within a constant factor [2].

[1] L. Hyafil and R. L. Rivest. Graph partitioning and constructing optimal decision trees are polynomial complete problems. 1973.

[2] K. Andreev and H. Racke. Balanced graph partitioning. 2004.